# Accion al activar Checkbox con JS and JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, checkbox, input

Tengo el siguiente fragmento de código, lo que estoy necesitando es que por medio de Javascript, preferentemente JQuery, extraer el valor del #input695 cada vez que se active el checkbox #695, teniendo en cuenta que en principio el input estara vacio

```html
<tbody id="tablaPrest">
  <tr>
    <td>Consulta Medica</td>
    <td>
      <input class="form-control" id="input695" value="">
     </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" id="695" autocomplete="off"> 
    </td>
```

Con esto estoy intentando extraer lo que contiene el input, pero no me esta funcionando

```js
 

  `$('#695').change(function(){
              extraer=$('#input695').textContent
              console.log(extraer)
            })`
```

Comment: Por favor agrega el código que tengas implementado en js. Acá estamos para guiarte no para hacer tus tareas.

Comment: Con esto estoy intentando extraer lo que contiene el input, pero no me esta funcionando

`$('#695').change(function(){
              extraer=$('#input695').textContent
              console.log(extraer)
            })`

Comment: edita tu pregunta y agrega el JS para que toda la comunidad lo vea.

Comment: Estas haciendo sopa `.textContent` no se encuentra si buscas en la especificación de jQuery. Si consultas sólo te ofrece referencias al método `.text()` debes usar tal método o en su lugar `$(selector).val()` que te devuelve el valor establecido en el atributo 'value'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bueno lo que debes hacer es lo siguiente

paso 1: Detectar el cambio

```
$("#695").change(function(){


})
```

paso 2: Verificar si esta marcada

```
$("#695").change(function(){

  if($("#695").prop("checked") == true)


})
```

paso 3: Tomar el valor del input

```
$("#695").change(function(){

  if($("#695"). prop("checked") == true){
    let extraer = $('#input695').val()
    console.log(extraer)
  }

})
```

Answer (score 2):

Con esto deberías de solucionar.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <td>Consulta Medica</td>
            <td>
                <input class="form-control" id="input695" value="">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" id="695" autocomplete="off"> 
            </td>
        </table>
    </body>
    <script>

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#695').change(function () {
                extraer = $('#input695').val();
                console.log(extraer)
            });
        });

    </script>
</html>
```